Precision-based calculation of mean change
I have two basic questions about SS calculation arounf the mean change, precision based )I'm a physician not biostatistician so sorry if questions are like extremely basic):

A colleague of mine suggeted using 0 Correlation for calculating the change to be conservative. My point is (that a conservative estimate could be a 0.5 correlation or 0.4), if Corr=0, meaning independency, there woudl be little point in bothering to calculate the change, better the post mean. Thoughts on that?
Independently of the issue, he calculated the change SD to input in the precision formula as SDchange=SQRT(VARpre/npre+VARpost/Npost), arguing that the parameter used in CI calculation for mean change is the SEM. I would have used SDchange=SQRT(VARpre+VARpost), and then thar SD input in the formula for a precision-based sampel size calculation.

My calculations: we calculated the within-subject standard deviation using a pre-test SD of 1.2 and a post-test SD of 0.8. Testing different correlations of 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, and 0.8, we obtained SDs change of 1.058, 0.963, 0.858, and 0.738, respectively. The precision for mean calculation, with a mean of 1, yielded 95% confidence intervals ranging from [0.913, 1.087] for an SD of 1.05 to [0.940, 1.060] for an SD of 0.73 with 564 subjects
Any thoughts on this?
BR
Alex
